# R datetime function

Tags: r, datetime

I am trying to generate date and time in this format below

```
2016-06-29T16:30:00
```

So curious to find out which R datetime function will return date and time in that format. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: A datetime, or in that format? I think you're looking for `as.POSIXct` and the like, but you really need to give more context on your problem.

Comment: @alistaire, date and time in that format :) the solution below by Psidom does the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `format` function does what you want:

```
format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
# [1] "2016-06-29T21:23:33"
```